# know in which interval of dates of 15 minutes is a date SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TIMETABLE
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(50), [StartDate] datetime, [EndDate] datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO TIMETABLE
    ([ID], [Name], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'John',  '2017-01-29 16:00:00.000', '2017-01-29 16:12:00.000'),
    (2, 'Mario',  '2017-01-29 16:17:00.000', '2017-01-29 16:29:00.000'),
    (3, 'Kate',  '2017-01-15 10:35:00.000', '2017-01-15 10:40:00.000'),
    (4, 'Maria', '2017-01-15 10:17:00.000', '2017-01-15 10:27:00.000'),
    (5, 'Oliver',  '2017-01-15 13:46:00.000', '2017-01-29 14:00:00.000')
;
```

And The result for this:

```
select * from TIMETABLE

ID  Name    StartDate               EndDate
1   John    2017-01-29T16:00:00Z    2017-01-29T16:12:00Z
2   Mario   2017-01-29T16:17:00Z    2017-01-29T16:29:00Z
3   Kate    2017-01-15T10:35:00Z    2017-01-15T10:40:00Z
4   Maria   2017-01-15T10:17:00Z    2017-01-15T10:27:00Z
5   Oliver  2017-01-15T13:46:00Z    2017-01-29T14:00:00Z
```

I want to know with a range from 15 mins in which range is the date, for example:

```
   ID   Name    StartDate               EndDate                HourRangeTime
    1   John    2017-01-29T16:00:00Z    2017-01-29T16:12:00Z   16:00
```

In the example the startdate and the enddate is in the range between 16:00 and 16:12 is in the range 16:00

The result it should be like this:

```
ID  Name    StartDate               EndDate                   HourRangeTime
1   John    2017-01-29T16:00:00Z    2017-01-29T16:12:00Z      16:00
2   Mario   2017-01-29T16:17:00Z    2017-01-29T16:29:00Z      16:15
3   Kate    2017-01-15T10:35:00Z    2017-01-15T10:40:00Z      10:30
4   Maria   2017-01-15T10:17:00Z    2017-01-15T10:27:00Z      10:15
5   Oliver  2017-01-15T13:46:00Z    2017-01-29T14:00:00Z      13:45
```

How can I fill the column HourRangeTime, take dates and see what range does it belong to?

[sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d2b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your seem focused on the `StartDate`.

A relatively general way to do this is to convert this to minutes and then truncate the minutes to the nearest 15 minutes.  Here is code:

```
select cast(dateadd(minute,
                    15 * (datediff(minute, 0,
                                   cast(StartDate as time)
                                  ) / 15
                         ), 0
                   ) as time)
```

This returns the result as a `time`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get difference and process future.

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime , EndTime) AS MinuteDiff 
FROM TIMETABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for your desired output:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(DATEPART(hh,StartDate), ':', 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,StartDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN '00'
            WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,StartDate) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '15'
            WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,StartDate) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30'
            WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,StartDate) BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '45'
        ELSE '00'
        END) AS HourRangeTime 
FROM TIMETABLE
```

OUTPUT:

```
HourRangeTime
-------------
16:00
16:15
10:30
10:15
13:45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
SELECT *,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR, [StartDate])) 
    + ':' 
    + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATEPART(MINUTE, [StartDate]) / 15) * 15)+'0',2) HourRangeTime FROM TIMETABLE
```